# What's the type for functions used as a dictionary value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

```py
Map: dict[str, object] = {
    "image" : Image.generate,
    "video" : Video.generate,
}
```

Here, `generate(json)` is a function in both cases. However I'm getting a typehint error that `"object" not callable mypy(error)`. What should be the appropriate type instead of `object` for the `Map`?

Comment: You mean they're `Callable`?

Comment: In that specific case, the type hint might not be needed at all since the type can be inferred from the dict literal.

Comment: You told the type checker that your dict can have arbitrary objects as values; as a result, it cannot assume that any given value is callable at *runtime*.

Comment: @Toggle The type hint isn't just to tell `mypy` what *is* in the `dict`, but what *can be put* in the dict.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict[str,Callable]` to allow *any* callable object as a value, but you might want to be more specific. At the very least, it sounds like the function must return a single string (the resulting JSON value), so you can write

```
dict[str, Callable[[...], str]]
```

to allow functions that take arbitrary arguments and return a `str`. If you know more about what the function can accept, you can replace `...` with one or more specific argument types.